# Why table scan on a Indexed View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, view, indexed-view

I created a table by copying 19972 rows (ID,FirstName,LastName) from Adventureworks.person.person table.
On this table I created a non-clustered index on Firstname Column.
Using this table I created an Indexed view with ID and FirstName column with unique Clustered index on ID.
When I query ID column from this view I get a TABLE SCAN. I was expecting to get a Clustered index seek. Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thank you.

```
Create View vIndexedView
with Schemabinding, Encryption
as
Select ID, FirstName
From dbo.RIDLookupTBL
where ID <=200
```

```
Create unique clustered index UCI_vIV_ID on vIndexedView(ID)
```

```
Select ID
From vIndexedView
Where ID = 20
```

[Table scan on indexed view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePdvv.png)

Comment: Use the `NOEXPAND` hint if you want to be sure it is used. Otherwise the views are expanded out and may or may not be matched later. Automatic index view matching only happens in Enterprise/Developer edition and only then if the optimizer gets around to considering it (cost for scanning only 19,972 rows may mean it never gets that far anyway)

Comment: Also see these great articles by Paul White: [Another Reason to Use NOEXPAND hints in Enterprise Edition](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints) (I wish that title said _even_ in Enterprise Edition) and [Indexed Views and Statistics](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/indexed-views-and-statistics).